# Android-Build error IllegalStateException

Tags: android, gradle

I have been working on an app for the last 2 months, I launched my app today and found this build error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

EDIT: I can't put the code because I have a lot of classes, how can I know where the error is ?

Comment: see the line number mentioned in log cat. it will there around somewhere

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild

Comment: @E.Abdel thanks it worked!